# How to make the lightning port of iphone output 5V power? like OTG on android phones

Tags: usb, iphone, lightning

## How to make the lightning port of iPhone output 5V power?

[image]

How to make the lightning port of iPhone output 5V power?

Just like the android phone, if I connect the ID pin to the ground then the phone will work as a USB host, after that it will output 5V power (the so-called **OTG** - *On The Go usb*).

> update
>
> I don't know why some people cast opposing votes to this the question.
>
> And I think this a quite normal question that many people can face. Perhaps you should check this product: Sandisk iXpad https://www.sandisk.com/ixpandflashdrive2
>   [image]
>   **I just confuse how these devices can output power by the lightning port.**

Comment: iPhones have a port for connecting lights? Wow! What will Apple think of next ??

Comment: Why is iPhone different? The OTG function is very useful. unless iPhone does not support the USB protocol ..

Answer (score 3):

Your question is vastly answered by: 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119707/how-much-power-can-be-drawn-from-the-lightning-connector-by-a-external-device

> Since Apple doesn't publicly commit to power levels or even pin
>   compatibility on the lightning connector, anyone interested in
>   learning how hardware should be designed to work with Apple's dock
>   connectors could choose to join the MFI program:
>
> https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ As a developer, Apple will
>   provide you with detailed hardware requirements, schematics and even
>   technical support. I haven't seen anyone take a current meter and volt
>   meter to the devices and post publicly, but wanted to make you aware
>   of one official avenue to get this sort of information across all of
>   Apple's iOS product line wether they use the 30 pin dock connector,
>   the lightning dock connector or some of the other specific iPod
>   connectors.
>
> quoting: Additionally, the pin out for lightning connectors [requires
>   an authentication chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_(connector)) according to wikipedia, so getting power
>   out of a lightning device involves software authentication before
>   power will flow.
>
> The article describing 8 pins that are active, indicates that when power flows into the phone (the
>   opposite of your use), pins 1 and 5 are ground and power respectively.
>   However, until your cable identifies itself to iOS, no power will be
>   provided.

Comment: then I can see that it's very difficult to design such a device because of the limitation of Apple company.

Answer (score -1):

Since Apple even communicates with USB Chargers, I would say you may need a Thunderbolt Controller.

[Mouser link](https://www.mouser.de/Semiconductors/Integrated-Circuits-ICs/Interface-ICs/I-O-Controller-Interface-IC/_/N-6j75g?P=1yy6dqs)

Comment: my question is how can the iPhone lightning port output power to supply the other devices like the Sandisk iXpand. connected to a charge adopter is another thing.

Comment: Yea, it will output the Power after it recognized the Device, connecting the Identification to the Ground maybe wont work for Apple Devices

Comment: that's my question, how to recognize the device and after that step, how to output the power?@Playa

Comment: *"it will output the Power after it recognized the Device"* - you can't recognize any device unless you provide the power first.

Comment: -1 Thunderbolt has nothing to do with Lightning